# What is the expiration time for "legacy" apns?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

The original APNS format - what is now called "legacy" - did not offer a way to specify message expiration (or retention). This feature was introduced later, in the "enhanced" APNS format, as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html).

Despite being old, this format is still supported and active. For practical reasons, I need to know what the retention behavior is. Is there any retention? is it maximal? or is there some value in between?

As an side:
For those of you who use the [java-apns lib](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns), if you're using the SimpleApnsNotification class, then you're using the "legacy" format mentioned above.

Comment: Of course, this question can be answered by empirically testing. However, I'm hoping to get a definitive answer, if has one.